# Upgrades to Carrera Crixus

Tags: cyclocross

Recently had my Tifosi bike stolen so need to buy a new bike and preferably want cyclocross. I am considering buying the cheap Carrera Crixus and modifying it, but what upgrades would be recommended on it?Or, does anyone know of any other cheap cx bikes that are worth modifiying, or just to be bought new for around 400? Appreciate any help

Comment: Hi Dan - this question has been closed as "off topic" because specific product brands/models and prices are both highly regional, and change over time.   As such, recommending a specific model is only useful for a short time and in a specific area of the world.   
Instead, consider trying out some bikes - the best bike is one that is comfortable to you, so it gets ridden.  You can learn more how SE works by browsing the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

Just buy the best bike you can get for the money you have. Component upgrades cost less money when bought as part of a whole bike, compared to being purchased and fitted separately.

As an example, the price difference between a bike fitted with 105 and one with Tiagra is a lot less than what a 105 groupset costs.

The difference can be defrayed by selling the original components as new take-offs, but it's a hassle and you probably still will not make up the difference.

If I were you I'd look for a used bike in good shape, rather than deal with Halfords level bikes.